# Nested bootstrap tabsets

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get nested tabsets. But there's a problem - the nested tabset doesn't work because of  `TypeError: Cannot read property '$parent' of undefined`

You can see it here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/xU9RibIL9k1D3m4GwB5z?p=preview

The html part (most important, controller is empty)

```
  <tabset>
    <tab heading="normal">
      <div>Content 1</div>
    </tab>
    <tab heading="nested">
      <div>
      <tabset>
        <tab heading="Nested One">
          <div>Nested Content 1</div>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="Nested Two">
          <div>Nested Content 2</div>
        </tab>
      </tabset>
      </div>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

(And no, I can't use ng-view and routing - because I don't want to lost contents of tabs when switched back - routing reloads tab content)

Comment: Known bug:  https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/1043  At the end you'll see an `ng-include` workaround

Comment: Funny thing, my original project is build with ng-include, so I have to find "a little" difference, which makes big problem :D

Comment: You're absolutely right! It isn't workaround for me, because I have to use ng-include for other reason ;D Great!

Comment: Any chance of linking to a working example?